# How to use expression as LAG() second parameter on MySQL 8 (like MSSQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to migrate this SQL SERVER query:

```
SELECT year, sales,   
    LAG(year-2, 2*(SELECT MIN(sales) FROM product_sales), sales/2.0 ) OVER (ORDER BY year) AS no_sense  
FROM product_sales;
```

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=d7e99f84ef44254cbae06cb645b285cb)

To **MySQL 8** (same query):

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=619dd8d8b6786589501dae3bfc4283ee)

Unfortunately I got this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '*(SELECT MIN(sales) FROM product_sales), sales/2.0 ) OVER (ORDER
>   BY year) AS no_' at line 2

Is it possible to "port" this query to mysql?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  This does not seem useful in any database.

Comment: it's just an example to empower a framework orm

Comment: I think that you want to use the LAG() but are not in a windowing function. Can you describe what you are trying to compute/

Comment: I want the same result from sqlserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** this answer is based on the Vignesh Kumar A 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58734424/2548147). 
>   So why MySQL 8 does not support that SQL Server syntax is already fully explained in his answer, i choose to not explain it double.

In MySQL 8 you would need to make a dynamic SQL query out of it, as offset param of `LAG()` does not support SQL expressions..

```
SET @sql = CONCAT("
SELECT
    year
  , sales
  , LAG(year-2,  ",(SELECT FLOOR(MIN(sales)) FROM product_sales),", sales/2.0 ) OVER (ORDER BY year) AS no_sense  
FROM product_sales;
");

PREPARE q FROM @sql;
EXECUTE q;
```

**Note:** `FLOOR()` is there to fix `19874.00` not giving a error on the lag function. 
Offcource you could rewite that `SET @sql := CONCAT("..")` part [different](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p8bqss1ZhpsJ22i6suXf8z/6), just use the writing style you understand the best.

**Result**

```
| year | sales | no_sense |
| ---- | ----- | -------- |
| 2017 | 55000 | 27500    |
| 2017 | 78000 | 39000    |
| 2017 | 49000 | 24500    |
| 2017 | 32000 | 16000    |
| 2018 | 41000 | 20500    |
| 2018 | 89651 | 44825.5  |
| 2018 | 19874 | 9937     |
| 2018 | 32562 | 16281    |
| 2019 | 87456 | 43728    |
| 2019 | 75000 | 37500    |
| 2019 | 96500 | 48250    |
| 2019 | 85236 | 42618    |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p8bqss1ZhpsJ22i6suXf8z/0)

This works because `PREPARE q FROM @sql;` generates this SQL. (Vignesh Kumar A answer)

```
SELECT 
   year  
 , sales  
 , LAG(year-2, 19874, sales/2.0 ) OVER (ORDER BY year) AS no_sense
FROM product_sales;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I hope this question can help people in next years when MySQL 8 be more popular.

Comment: *"I hope this question can help people in next years when MySQL 8 be more popular. "* Maybe @celsowm still Gordon Linoff's comment *"What are you trying to accomplish? This does not seem useful in any database."* on your question is very valid, this does not seam very usefull ..

Answer (score 1):

This is because `offset` parameter in `LAG` function. In `MYSQL` offset will not accept the expression or column and it will accept only positive number, whereas `MSSQL` will accept all except negative nos.

**MYSQL**

`offset` - The `offset` is the number of rows back from the current row from which to get the value. The offset must be zero or a literal positive integer. If offset is zero, then the LAG() function evaluates the expression for the current row. If you don’t specify the offset, then the LAG() function uses one by default.

**MSQSQL**

`offset` - The number of rows back from the current row from which to obtain a value. If not specified, the `default` is 1. **offset can be a column, subquery, or other expression** that evaluates to a positive integer or can be implicitly converted to bigint. offset cannot be a negative value or an analytic function.

May be you can try the same query with maximum number.

```
SELECT year, sales,   
    LAG(year-2, 19874, sales/2.0 ) OVER (ORDER BY year) AS no_sense  
FROM product_sales;
```

**[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36104d097eee2c1e5da4b5ae1e6e32c8)**

Comment: Such a pity, I've tried using @variable but the result was empty: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3b4b0396936cc68a271ce225f613fe2